# ubuntu is extremely laggy and choppy

Tags: ubuntu-mate

so I restored and upgraded a 14 dollar dell laptop from 2008, and I installed ubuntu 16.04 and it ran fine, I had no WIFI, so I did some updates to 16.04 and it became really really laggy, loading up tabs is fast and stuff, but the cursor moves at 2fps, I thought it was my hardware, so I installed ubuntu mate 16.04 cause I like the feel and look of it more then 18.04 but still really laggy and choppy performance, I assumed it was my desktop and I installed xfce4, same thing.. extremely laggy, and when I open Firefox everything locks up and freezes

(and Wi-Fi still doesn't work but it doesn't work on windows either)

if it helps the specs of the laptop is, 4gb ddr2 ram, intel core 2 duo P9500, NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M. i think there more here https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Latitude-E6500.12268.0.html

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers if available.

Answer (score 0):

First `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to enter the terminal

Second, `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to remove the current drivers

Then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`

Then `sudo apt-get update`

Then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`

`lsmod | grep nvidia` to see the status of the installation and after that just reboot

Comment: didn't work :( I tried to install nvidia-390, but it didn't work, so I installed nvidia-340 which is the correct driver for my dell latitude e6500, still didn't work. I forgot to mention before I had went into additional drivers and tried all the 3 drivers available. I had no luck with any of them